# Increment an integer variable in a Constructor in a derived class Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class DevelopedPlanetClass

```
Inherits PlanetClass

Private _GDP As Double
Private _Number As Integer

Public Sub New(DName As String, DNumWages As Integer, DGDP As Double)

    MyBase.New(DName, DNumWages)
    _GDP = DGDP
    _Number += 1 (PROBLEM.... Does not increment when the constructor is called )

End Sub

Public Overloads Function CalcMinWage(GDP As Double) As Double

    Return GDP / _Number

End Function
```

End Class

Comment: Figured it out ......... You make _Number Shared

Comment: Private Shared _Number As Integer